# How to insert subitem into list without breaking layout?

Tags: support, markdown, list

What I want to see in final (i.e. `Outer begin` x-pos is same as `outer end` x-pos, top & bottom margins for `inner` approx. equal):

> [image: desired]

What I really see (too large v-space before `inner`) as picture:

> [image: inreal]

Live example:

---

- Outer begin

  - inner

  outer end

---

Code for this:

```
* Outer begin
 * inner

 outer end
```

Is it possible to reach desired view using an existing markdown syntax on Stack Exchange sites?

Is it a bug in markdown when I see too large v-space?

As it turned out the android-app displays the list as necessary:

> [image: andriod-list]

Comment: @Cai so, it is not possible to achieve desired view only using markdown (i.e. w/o html tags)? And problem arises from CSS style which used in SE sites?

Comment: Yup appears to be duplicate indeed, and indeed something that markdown simply can't support.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think we need to make another post, about difference in list representation (layout) in android-app, web/iOS-app.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry forgot about this, I've been traveling... it's just a result of the different markup and CSS output from list items with only text vs list items with child elements

Comment: @Cai Did I undestood you correctly, that the problem can be fixed if SE will use another CSS on sites?

Comment: It could certainly be fixed with CSS yes, wait till I'm back at a computer and I'll have a look exactly how :)

Comment: The android and iOS apps are totally different issue, I don't think they're even using the stands markdown "engine", but yes worth trying to post something that will ask about the differences.

Comment: [Better nested list styling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287967/better-nested-list-styling)