# Adding indented text after a 2nd-level list in a nested list messes up the spacing of the outer list

Tags: bug, markdown, list

If I have a bulleted list and I want to add some indented text after a certain element, I do something like this:

```
- Point 1
- Point 2

  Indented text

- Point 3
```

..which renders like this:

- Point 1
- Point 2

  Indented text
- Point 3

<sub>So for, so good.</sub>

---

Now, if I have a second-level list like this:

- Point 1

  - Point 1.1
  - point 1.2
- Point 2

..and I want to add some indented text before `Point 2`, I do something like this:

```
- Point 1
  - Point 1.1
  - point 1.2  

  Indented text
- Point 2
```

I expect to see some spacing above `Indented text` just like the first example. However, when I do that, the line spacing gets messed up; no spacing above `Indented text` and some additional spacing is added above the child/2nd-level list.

See it in action:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Are you wanting it indented to Point 1 or Point 1.2?

Comment: I want to indent it to `Point`, otherwise, I could just add a `<br>` after `Point 1.2` and remove the empty line below it (even though this won't add vertical spacing between the two lines but I think it's good enough).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better list spacing (nested lists and/or lists with multiple paragraphs)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287967/better-list-spacing-nested-lists-and-or-lists-with-multiple-paragraphs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Exchange Markdown rendering shows incorrect list spacing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347187/282094),  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287903/282094